# SQLIte Errors (Return ArrayList with object)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need help to return an ArrayList object that contains the stduent_id of the students, and select only the student that has the status either as 'Graduated' or 'Inactive'

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "TPRRHSCHOOL";
private static final String TABLE_STUDENT = "student";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "student_id";
private static final String COLUMN_STATUS = " status";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



public ArrayList<String> getStudents(){
ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = null; 
if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++){
Cursor rawQuery (String status, String[] 'Graudate', String[] "Inactive")
cursor.moveToNext();

db.close;
return getStudents;
```

<-I seriously have no idea which part is wrong, as the tutorials has lots of jargons that look alien to me, and I'hv been trying out since yesterday, so I sincerely need your guys help!->

Comment: You should add tag with programming language you are using.

Comment: done ! Thank you!

Comment: Few comments: (1) though I don't think this is an issue, you have an extra blank in the definition of COLUMN_STATUS (you have `" status"`); (2) You are not presenting what is wrong (e.g. error message, result, anything); (3) Where are you submitting the query and opening the cursor?

Comment: The language of your program (as per @PetSerAl question) is **JAVA**, not SQL or any other of the tags you added.

Comment: Can you please **indent** your code?

Comment: @FDavidov all of the tags I see are correct. This absolutely is a SQL, sqlite, and Android question. The only tag I would argue against is Java.

Comment: @MrMannWood, I normally refrain from arguing with people that still have a long way to go before becoming a valuable partner for an argument. This is one of those cases. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With the given information, I'll assume that you are currently getting a NullPointerException, and also don't know how to query against a SQL database.

I'll start with a direct answer to your question, and end with some resources that will help you understand what's going on.

The NPE is coming from initializing the Cursor to null, and immediately calling getCount() on it. To properly initialize your cursor, you need to create a query. I imagine it would look similar to:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(
        TABLE_STUDENT,
        new String[] { /* this is an array of column names that I want */ },
        COLUMN_STATUS + " in (?, ?)", // this is Prepared Statement syntax
        new String[] { 'Graudate', 'Inactive' },
        null,
        null,
        null  // Assuming you don't care about order
);
```

What this is doing is creating an SQL statement similar to

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE status IN ('Graudate', 'Inactive')
```

where * will be replaced by the actual column names that you need.

You may now use the cursor to retrieve the data:

```
if(cursor != null) { //makes sure that the query returned a cursor
    try {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) { //makes sure that the cursor contains data
            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(cursor.getCount());
            do {
                Student s = new Student();
                // do this for each variable in student
                s.setSomeVar(
                    cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("SOME_COLUMN_NAME")
                    )
                );
            } while(c.moveToNext()) // position the cursor at the next index
            return students;
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

For detail around creating and understanding the above cursor, please look at the javadoc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). You should also get comfortable with SQL. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) has the basics.

As with most things that were put into Android in the early days, the SqlLite query structure is overly verbose, and can be off-putting to newcomers. I recommend googling any terms you don't know as you run into them.

I recommend:

- SQL select statement
- SQL prepared statement
- Android Sqlite cursor example

Comment: Thank you very much for your help MrMannWood! I definatly will buck up on my sqlite langauge! Your explanation is so much clearer! Thanks a million!